# Expansion of universe faster then speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, universe, space

Watching one of the shows on discovery channel, I got to know that during the starting phase of universe its speed should have been faster then speed of light. But then didnt einstein say that nothing can go faster then the speed of light. IF it is true then the universe should have not expanded at that rate? note that I searched for this post but couldnt find any that solves my questions, except for one which is closely related to my question "Why is the age of universe 13.7 billion years?" Thank You

Comment: Its not the speed of universe which is faster than light but the speed of particle horizon, which is the distance of observable universe. It is greater than speed of light c, because the universe was expanding during its initial phase.

Comment: i get it @seeking_infinity